# Изменить значения других элементов без javascript

Tags: css

```
.rate1{background-image: url(images/rating/rating1.png); margin-top:53px;}
.rate1:hover{
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

При наведении на объект, серый фильтр убирается. элемент загорается. Как без javascript сделать так, чтобы при наведении на 3 элемент, загорался также второй и первый. При наведении на четвертый загорался 4,3,2,1

```
p:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ p:nth-of-type(4){ color:blue; } срабатывает. 
p:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ p:nth-of-type(1){ color:blue; } уже нет
```

И картинка звезды стоит у класса rate2. Как без javascript сделать так, чтобы когда был активный инпут, его родительский элемент загорался, ну и слева соседи загорались соответственно?

```
<li class="rate2"><input type="radio" value = "Общий: 2" name="common0"class="inpu2"></li>
```

Вопрос все еще актуален

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bHNPN/

Comment: Спасибо. Но у меня вид другой:
<li class="rate2"><input type="radio" value = "Общий: 2" name="common0"class="inpu2"></li>

И картинка звезды стоит у класса rate2. Как без javascript сделать так, чтобы когда был активный инпут, его родительский элемент загорался, ну и слева соседи загорались соответственно?

Comment: вам шашечки или ехать ?

Answer (score 1):

[CSS hover over one paragraph, change background of the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393905/css-hover-over-one-paragraph-change-background-of-the-previous-one)

Демка: http://jsfiddle.net/9KFb2/2/

Comment: p:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ p:nth-of-type(4){
color:blue;
}
срабатывает. 
p:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ p:nth-of-type(1){
color:blue;
}
уже нет